# "Make Homepage" doesn't work, results in access denied

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site

I can't get to the homepage of my site using just the root url, but it works if I specify the whole path. For example, this works fine:

```
http://server.domain.com/pages/page1.aspx
```

But the following results in "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you":

```
http://server.domain.com
```

While on page1.aspx, I clicked the "make homepage" button, and that gives me a success message.

SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, in a site using the publishing feature.

edit: this site has been around for months, and this problem just started today.

Comment: If you try to set the Welcome Page using Site Settings will it work?

Comment: No. But clicking "make homepage" did successfully update the setting in the welcome page. But I changed it in the welcome page and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have your admin check the permissions on the web application's virtual directory in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories... We had something like this happen and it was a result of service pack change where the web app's virtual directory was rebuilt and the permissions were not correct.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check:

1. Is the home page checked in and published?
2. Is the master page checked in and published?

Also, for the purposes of troubleshooting, try disabling Minimal Download Strategy feature.